# Exchange 2010 Autodiscover DNS configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange-2010, autodiscovery

I'm unable to get the Autodiscover of Exchange 2010 working.
Our email accounts are  name@company **.com**
and our AD is company **.local**

When I open Outlook 2010 and Ctrl + RMK on the icon and select 'Test E-mail AutoConfiguration' I see this:

```
 SMTP=myname@company.com
Attempting URL https://exchange1.COMPANY.LOCAL/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml found through SCP
Autodiscover to https://exchange1.COMPANY.LOCAL/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml starting
GetLastError=12007; httpStatus=0.
Autodiscover to https://exchange1.COMPANY.LOCAL/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml Failed (0x800C8203)
Autodiscover to https://company.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml starting
GetLastError=12029; httpStatus=0
Autodiscover to https://company.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml Failed (0x800C8203)
Autodiscover to https://autodiscover.company.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml starting
GetLastError=12007; httpStatus=0.
Autodiscover to https://autodiscover.company.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml Failed (0x800C8203)
Local autodiscover for company.com starting
Local autodiscover for company.com Failed (0x8004010F)
Redirect check to http://autodiscover.company.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml starting
Srv Record lookup for http://autodiscover.company.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml Failed (0x80072EE7)
Srv Record lookup for company.com starting
Srv Record lookup for company.com Failed (0x8004010F)
```

If I go via my browser on a client pc to:

```
https://exchange1/Autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
```

I see an XML reply (so I guess this is the autodiscover URL that should be used) 
(exchange1 is the servername.).
This is what I see in my browser:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
- <Response>
- <Error Time="15:21:30.8211336" Id="2980235674">
  <ErrorCode>600</ErrorCode> 
  <Message>Invalid Request</Message> 
  <DebugData /> 
  </Error>
  </Response>
  </Autodiscover>
```

When I try this:

```
  https://exchange1.company.local/Autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
```

It ask for my username / password and if I enter them I see the same XML message.
Now on my DC in the DNS Manager I have this:

```
DCSERVER
- Forward Lookup Zones
-- _msdcs.COMPANY.LOCAL
--- dc
--- domains
--- gc
--- pdc
-- COMPANY.LOCAL
--- _msdcs
--- sites
--- _tcp   <---------
--- _udp
--- DomainDnsZones
--- ForestDnsZones
```

Under the COMPANY.LOCAL > _tcp  I have added an SRV record:

```
_autodiscover    Service Location (SRV) [0][0][443]  exchange1.company.local    static
```

Could anyone see what I'm missing or misconfigured?

**Update:**

**1)**
    Get-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory

Gives me:

```
Name                                    Server                                  InternalUrl
----                                    ------                                  -----------
Autodiscover (Default Web Site)         EXCHANGE1
```

Looks like I need to set an InternalUrl also.
Is this correct?:

```
Set-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory -Identity 'Autodiscover (Default Web Site)' -InternalUrl 'https://autodiscover.company.local'
```

**2)**

in the DNS Manager, I only have an SRV _autodiscover Record in _tcp as said in this post.
Is this enough?
Or should I add an A record with these settings in 'Forward Lookup Zones > COMPANY.LOCAL'?:

```
Name: autodiscover
Type: Host (A)
Data: <ip of exchange>
```

Comment: I've updated the post. is that update correctly?

Comment: When creating an A record, I also created the PTR record. Not sure if this is needed. Let's see if this works.

Comment: everything seems fine now :)

Comment: I've switched my comments to an "answer".  If that didn't fix it and you figured it out yourself, please post your own answer and accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about on the Exchange side...what are the internal/external URLs configured as? Do you have an A record in DNS for "autodiscover.company.com" (or autodiscover.company.local internally) and does your SSL cert have both names listed?

Set the internalURL and create an A record...both internally and externally (using autodiscover.company.com) if you want the clients to be able to autodiscover from outside too.